# Completely disabling dates out of the given range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, daterangepicker

I was using this plugin https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker/ for a daterange picker. I want to completely disable/hide the dates that are out of the given start and end date range. Can some one help me with this please.

```
  $('#datrange').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    timePickerIncrement: 30,
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A',
    startDate: moment().subtract('days', 29),
  endDate: moment()
  });
```

This is the code I use now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the documentation on the page *you* linked, I'd say you need these options:

> minDate: (Date object, moment object or string) The earliest date a user may select
>   maxDate: (Date object, moment object or string) The latest date a user may select

Which probably work something like this:

```
$('#datrange').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    timePickerIncrement: 30,
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A',
    startDate: moment().subtract('days', 29),
    endDate: moment(),
    minDate: moment().subtract('days', 100),
    maxDate: moment().add('days', 100) // Using moment objects as a example.
});
```

Comment: Sure just took me some time @Cerbrus

Comment: Yea, the 15 minute delay can be a pain.